# C: Different pointer casting

Tags: c, pointers

Where is the difference between the two `void*` to `long` casting/converting (code taken from Advanced Programming in Unix Environment) and why is it possible/allowed to write the 2nd case:

```
int complong(const void *arg1, const void *arg2)
{
  long l1 = *(long *)arg1;
  long l2 = *(long *)arg2;
  // ...
}
```

vs

```
void* thr_fn(void *arg)
{
  long idx = (long)arg;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? +1, I think it's a good question and the second example is a form that could surprise people new to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is a form often encountered with thread functions. The pointer argument can be used to store an integer.

```
void* thr_fn(void *arg)
{
   long idx = (long)arg;
   // ...
}
```

For example, `pthread_create` function takes several arguments and one is a pointer to a function that returns a `void *` and has a `void *` parameter.

If your function has several arguments you can pass a pointer to structure type with different members as the `void *`. But if your function has a single integer parameter, instead of using a pointer one can just pass the integer value to the `void *` argument and then converts it in the function as a integer.

For example:

```
thr_fn((void *) 42);
```

It passes the value `42` to the function.

Answer (score 4):

When you cast `void*` to `long*`, you get a pointer pointing to a long value with the same address of the original pointer. When you cast `void*` to `long`, you are taking the address that the pointer points to as a number.

Comment: Oh, I was looking it wrong - he was taking the address. But is it better to use ptrdiff_t in this case or size_t or something else?

Comment: @Bade Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

> why is it possible/allowed to write the 2nd case?

```
long idx = (long)arg;
```

`arg` is a pointer and the value the pointer variable can hold is a valid memory location or NULL. So what you do is just assign this value to a `long` type variable, which is totally valid and hence this code snippet gets compiled.

Comment: *arg is a pointer and it holds a memory location as its value* Are you sure?

Comment: no, the pointer is used here to hold an integer and not to store a pointer value.

Comment: @ouah I meant the address is read as long and stored in the `long` type variable